# Image file corruption when trying to resize and convert file

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to resize a .PNG file and convert it to .jpg.

I have been having issues with some PNG where the transparant background will turn into blocky orange with lines going through it and the semi-transparent shadows will turn into block black.

Here is my code:

```
<cfimage 
    action="convert" 
    source="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\wheels\Large\#serverfile#" 
    destination="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\wheels\Large\#replace(serverfile,'.png', '-1000.jpg')#">
<cfimage action = "resize"
    height = "1000"
    width="1000"
    source = "#app_sysfilepath_site#images\wheels\Large\#replace(serverfile, '.png', '-1000.jpg')#"
    destination = "#app_sysfilepath_site#images\wheels\Large\#replace(serverfile, '.png', '-1000.jpg')#"
    overwrite = "yes">
```

Funny thing is this happens on some PNG's but not on others.

Comment: I would begin with looking at the differences between a png file without a delay and a png file with a delay. Reproduce the differences one at a time, yourself, and see if you can nail it down. This post looks like a good tutorial: http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/04/getting-an-images-information-using-the-cfimage-tag-in-coldfusion/

Comment: interesting.  Report to bugbase.adobe.com and attach the broken PNG in the bug report, then post a link here?

Comment: @cfqueryparam: I can't anything about PNG's with and without delays online. Is that a typo? I dumped 2 images, one that works and one that has problems and all the properties are the same (except for the image size before)

Comment: @Henry, yeah, that's a good idea. I'll send them a bug report

Comment: I've reread my comment a dozen times, I don't see a typo (but eyes play tricks like that). You said that some png's cause this problem but others don't. There *should* be some kind of difference between the two but perhaps there is not. In any case, submitting it as a bug as a good idea but if you can identify a difference, that makes Adobe's job perhaps a little easier.

Comment: I noticed an error when uploading a png to my site yesterday. Not had a chance to look at it yet. Will report back if I find anything. I am also resizing it.

Comment: Well, I have researched and tested different ideas and have gotten nowhere with this. Anyone have any workaround suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having some issues in the past with .png files. There are four types of png's of which I am aware:

1. PNG-8 (256 colors)
2. PNG-24 (16 million colors)
3. PNG-32 (support full Alpha Transparency)
4. PNG (Fireworks layered)

If i had to guess i would say that you are having problems with png-32 files. I advice you to check your function with these different file types, and see which one produces the bad result.

Comment: How can I tell if a PNG is PNG-8, PNG-24 or PNG-32?

Comment: In windows, right click the image -> tab details -> bit depth